# How to access specific elements in list?

Tags: r, list, element

I have a large list containing 180 elements.  For example, I can access the 115th element in the list by using the following call:

```
> mylist[115]

[[115]]
     OBJECTID CELL_ID              QUADNAME STATE_CODE MRC_CODE     QUADID N_LATITUDE
1994     1995  309458 Bucklin Reservoirs SW         WY 42107-D4 4210737_sw    42.4375
     S_LATITUDE E_LONGITUD W_LONGITUD EXTENT_TYP BOTTOM    TOP_  LEFT_    RIGHT_
1994     42.375       -107       -108          S 42.375 42.4375 -107.5 -107.4375
          FIPS_C Shape_Leng Shape_Area utm_zone
1994 56007 56025   24162.04   35680939       13
```

How can I create a dataframe containing all of the "QUADID" attributes (e.g. 4210737_sw) in all of the elements in the list?

Comment: the structure of `mylist[115]` is unclear to me. What kind of object is that? Can you provide a `dput` of it?

Comment: @David `mylist` was created using the `returnList` parameter in the `over` function (sp package): http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/sp/docs/aggregate.Spatial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the `QUADID` value for each element of `mylist` you can try:

```
    sapply(mylist,function(x) x$QUADID)
```

This supposing that each element of your list has the same structure of what you showed for the 115th element in your OP. If that is not the case, you should give more details about `mylist` and be more precise about what's your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
require(data.table)
a <- data.frame(OJECTID = 1995, QUADID = "4210737_sw")
b <- data.frame(OJECTID = 1995, QUADID = "5145228_sw")
c <- data.frame(OJECTID = 1995, QUADID = "4210737_sw")
l <- list(a, b, c)

rbindlist(lapply(l, FUN = function(x) if(x$QUADID == "4210737_sw"){x}))
```